# opencv trackbar not adjustable

Tags: c++, opencv, trackbar

I'm trying to add an opencv trackbar to adjust the threshold value that I'm using for a binary threshold.

If I only display the trackbar, then I can slide it around as expected, but when I also display the video from my laptop camera in a second window, the trackbar gets stuck in one position and can't be moved. I think it may have to do with how I'm passing the threshold_value, but I couldn't seem to find any solution.

Here's my code:

```
#include "opencv2/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/videoio.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h> 

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

//Function Headers
void on_trackbar(int, void*);

// Global variables
int threshold_value = 30;
Mat frame_gray;

String face_cascade_name = "/opencv-3.0.0/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
String window_name = "Capture";
String trackbarWindowName = "TrackBars";

int main( void )
{
    VideoCapture capture;
    Mat frame;

    //create windows and trackbar
    namedWindow(trackbarWindowName, WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    namedWindow(window_name, WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    createTrackbar("threshold", trackbarWindowName, &threshold_value, 255, on_trackbar);

    //Load the face cascade
    face_cascade.load( face_cascade_name );

    //Read the video stream
    capture.open( 0 );
    printf("opened webcam\n");

    while ( capture.read(frame) )
    {
        if( frame.empty() )
        {
            printf(" --(!) No captured frame -- Break!");
            break;
        }

        cvtColor( frame, frame_gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY );
        threshold( frame_gray, frame_gray, threshold_value, 255, 1);
        imshow( window_name, frame_gray);
        int c = waitKey(10);
        if( (char)c == 27 ) { break; } // escape

    }
    return 0;
    }

void on_trackbar(int, void*){
    printf("hello\n");
    printf("%d\n", threshold_value);
}
```

Comment: Your code is working fine for me. Please make sure that the code you posted actually doesn't work for you.

Comment: I'm running exactly what's posted and it doesn't work. Every once in a while I can get the trackbar to jump, but I have no control over it whatsoever. I am using a new macbook so I don't think that my laptop is too slow, I'm wondering if it could be an OS X thing?

Comment: No idea, works ok on Win8.1. Good luck!

Comment: I have found you need the `waitKey()` parameter to be *at least* 20 on my Mac for it to work reliably. No idea why!

Comment: @MarkSetchell, thank you I had to set the `waitKey()` to at least 20 ms on my mac as well